# How to read in csv until the number of fields is too large

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv which I read in with:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

All the rows have 37 fields until one with 38 and from there it is corrupted. How can I just read in the rows with 37 fields?

Comment: You can specify the nrows like df = pd.read_csv("file.csv",nrows=37)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the doc : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

> error_bad_lines : boolean, default True
>
> Lines with too many fields (e.g. a csv line with too many commas) will by default cause an exception to be raised, and no DataFrame will
>   be returned. If False, then these “bad lines” will dropped from the
>   DataFrame that is returned.

So you can use :

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

But it might be better editing your .csv file and fix the concerned row properly. :)

Comment: Thank you. I need this to be automated so any preprocessing would also have to be in the script. Is there a nice way to count the number of fields in each row?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, if you want to work entirely with Python you can try the module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to preprocess errors. Good luck with your project !

Comment: Apparently `import csv
def f(s):return map(len,csv.reader(s.split("\n"))` let's you count the number of fields in each line which will basically solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a range of columns, just have to unpack it with `*`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=[*range(37)])
```

Comment: btw, Ofer, you can create this list by passing it to a list constructor as well, rather than using `*`, like this: `usecols=list(range(37))`. And if you use Python2, then `range` will automatically be a list and not a generator

Comment: That's true, you can edit those details in if you want, or i'll do it later (on mobile now)

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to preprocess the csv file, leave only the lines you are interested with and proceed to using `pd.read_csv` method as you normally do.

However, if you would like to try, you can have a look at the read_csv documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), it seems that there are some useful options there like `skiprows` for example

Comment: Is there are a nice way to count the number of fields in each row for the preprocessing?